# Udev symlink creation issues

Tags: udev

I am writing a udev rule to create a symlink for a usb camera, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The line below has been added to a file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-econ.rules

however i have unable to get the symlink working. I have tried restarted the udev service, rebooting the computer, and unplugging and replugging the device into the computer.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="video", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2560", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c110", ATTRS{serial}=="321CC601", SYMLINK+="usb_camera"
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add output of `udevadm info -a /dev/...`

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is syntactically correct. However you may want to check a few simple things.

**0)** Get rid of the `ATTRS{serial}=="321CC601",` bit. You don't need it (*EDIT* ->) unless you have several otherwise identical devices you need to distinguish by serial #.

**1)** Be sure to correctly identify your usb device.

```
# plug your device in a convenient usb port
$ lsusb  # <- check IDs for vendor and product
$ udevadm monitor --property 
# Above (^^^^) will monitor your device events continuously, 
# in particular every thing that is plugged/unplugged in a usb port.
# Unplug yr device and type CTRL-C in terminal to stop monitoring
```

**2)** Check that the IDs you noted down previously correspond to the output of `udevadm monitor --property` as you unplugged your device.

**3)** Make sure that `"SUBSYSTEM=="..."` fits the bill. 
It may be correct, but for a usb camera with a storage area (I assume maybe wrongly that it is yr case), you mostly see properties such as: 
`SUBSYSTEM=usb`, `SUBSYSTEM=scsi_host`, `SUBSYSTEM=scsi`, `SUBSYSTEM=scsi_disk`, `SUBSYSTEM=scsi_device`, `SUBSYSTEM=scsi_generic`, ...
OR
replace the test on `SUBSYSTEM` by a test on `ID_TYPE=="..."`

HTH. Feedback welcome.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I have confirmed that all the id's are correct, though the subsystem should actually be video4linux. changing that did not fix it however. I do actually need the serial as I will have two otherwise identical devices which i need to distinguish between.

Comment: Ah ! ;-(   I am at my wit's end already. T'is always difficult to troubleshoot this on AU.

Answer (score 0):

If you're matching on the `video4linux` subsystem, you need to use attributes that are available on that level.

To view the hierarchy of attributes, use `udevam` with the current `videoX` device assigned to your webcam:

```
$ udevadm info -a /dev/video0
  looking at device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/video4linux/video0':
    KERNEL=="video0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{dev_debug}=="0"
    ATTR{index}=="0"
    ATTR{name}=="GENERAL WEBCAM: GENERAL WEBCAM"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="uvcvideo"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="GENERAL WEBCAM"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1':
    KERNELS=="1-1.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2247"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1b3f"
    ATTRS{product}=="GENERAL WEBCAM"
    ATTRS{serial}=="JH0909_20201026_v004"
    ...
```

In this case, you can see that `ATTRS{idProduct}` and `ATTRS{idVendor}` are defined in the block with `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`, but not in the block with `SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"`. In that block, there is no product or vendor ID, nor a serial number. However, in my case I can use the `ATTR{name}` to filter this webcam (since I only have one of these attached):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux", ATTR{name}=="GENERAL WEBCAM: GENERAL WEBCAM", SYMLINK+="webcamUsb"
```

For more information, make sure to read http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html.